# PDF viewer crashes when creating complex picture in Tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, viewers

I've been [creating an image using Tikz](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8oqQK.png) and everything works fine, however the code is rather long (~270 lines). I'm highlighting this aspect because I think it's the reason why my PDF viewer often crashes when typesetting, and since I need to typeset a lot of times to make sure the picture is properly progressing, this quickly becomes very annoying.

So, I have two questions:

1. Why is the viewer crashing? All the calculations have been done by the time it opens, because the process disappears from the Processes' list. While the picture *is* complex, the PDF is only 25KB. Am I missing something?
2. What can I do to solve this problem? If there is a solution to begin with, of course.

Comment: Cool picture -- but *with TikZ*?!

Comment: @jon Yes, I did it using Tikz. :D [Here's an overview of my code](http://i.stack.imgur.com/037UD.png).

Comment: The art work is impressive, using TikZ.  Does it crash when using different PDF viewers?

Comment: @R.Schumacher The crash is not regular: it will crash sometimes and sometimes not when using Skim (typesetting). If I use Preview to open the PDF and I start zooming in and out, then it will crash. I haven't tested too much concerning Preview. But it used to crash also when using Textmate (and initially, I thought that was the issue), but the same happens with Sublime Text 2 + Skim.

Comment: Thanks, by the way, it's not an original work. It's based off [this picture](http://st.depositphotos.com/1536490/1691/v/450/depositphotos_16916479-Mountain-landscape.jpg). :D

Comment: Still impressive being done in Tikz.  Is your MacTex installation up to date, in particular the Tizk modules? Have you tried the Acrobat reader?  Reason, effectively Acrobat sets the standard for PDF.

Comment: @R.Schumacher I wanted to update from Tex Live, but I get this error: "**Unable to find a valid update server** - Either a network problem exists or the TeX Live version on the server does not match.  If this problem persists on further attempts, you may need to try a different repository."

Comment: I'm not a Mac user, but have you read the section on update in https://www.tug.org/texlive/ documentation and helps?

Comment: You on TL 2014 or 2015? Can't update 2014 anymore. (Note: I also can't speak about Macs.)

Comment: You should consider submitting your code to [Texample.net](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/). Information on contributing is [here](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/contribute/).

Comment: Can you isolate part of the code as responsible for the issue? It is hard to see how this question might get answered right now. (What is the tiny image of your code supposed to tell us exactly?) I have an image for which the TikZ code is 2217 lines long (counting everything so it will be fewer than this - just the `wc` output) so I don't think ~300 should be a problem per se.

Comment: @cfr The image of the code was just me sharing it, not related to the question. But you think that maybe just a part might be responsible? I didn't think about that, to be honest.

Comment: @DJP Not if it generates a PDF which crashes the viewer! I mean, that would be a wonderful thing to do when the problem is resolved. Although, I am not clear about the legality given that the image is a copy.

Comment: @Alenanno Did the crashes always occur from when you started work on it? Or did they start later? If later, maybe you can retrace to the point they started. Might not help, but it is hard to know what else to suggest. Or just try the usual bisecting method, of course. If the crashes always occurred, I don't know what to say: it is hard to see why merely intending to create a particular image should cause your viewer to crash in anticipation of the future burden!

Comment: The crashes are always related to shadings. Your viewer is not compatible with the new PDF specifications. Unfortunately you are bound to Adobe Acrobat or nothing. There is no shortcut or remedy for this. Adobe sets the standards and other viewers follow from a distance. TikZ developers however follow the developments closely.

Comment: @percusse So it's a known issue? I thought it was just me! I'll try switching to Adobe Reader (I wanted to change anyway) and see what happens. Thanks for the suggestion!